# How to define and use kafka host name in docker compose

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, containers

I want to have some containers use kafka to push data
and I have referred to this repo,
https://github.com/ktechhub/deploy_kafka_docker

after I changed the "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME" to 127.0.0.1 in docker-compose.yaml
and "kafka_server" to 127.0.0.1 in producer.py and consumer.py
then it can be ran successfully

Now I want to base on this and modify files to have 2 more new containers which are producer container and consumer container.

my modified folder structure becomes:

```
consumer
  - consumer.py
  - Dockerfile
producer
  - producer.py
  - Dockerfile
docker-compose.yaml
```

then my docker-compose.yaml file will look like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  producer:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./producer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"

  consumer:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./consumer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8889:8889"

  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    container_name: ktech_zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: ktech_kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    expose:
      - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test_topic:1:1"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: 4073741824
      KAFKA_LOG_SEGMENT_BYTES: 1073741824
      KAFKA_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 300000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Docker file in consumer folder:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
COPY consumer.py /
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install kafka-python
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "consumer.py"]
```

Dockerfile in producer folder:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
COPY producer.py /
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install kafka-python
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "producer.py"]
```

In producer container just run producer.py, and in consumer container only run consumer.py.

But seems the connection has problem between containers and it shows kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable.

How should I define the value of "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME" in docker-compose.yaml file and the value of "kafka_server" in producer.py and consumer.py files to make them work? or any other modification?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> in short, use the **environment** defined in docker-compose.yml, for consumer/producer get access to kafka.

**below is some suggestions from a newbee of kafka.**

##### 1. the content of docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  producer:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./producer
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment: 
      # this is you local server IP
      # this may should be set to the service_name: kafka(but i'm little confused of this)
      kafka_server: kafka:9092
    command: python producer.py
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  consumer:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./consumer
    ports:
      - "8889:8889"
    environment: 
      # this is you local server IP
      kafka_server: kafka:9092
    command: python consumer.py
    depends_on:
      - kafka
......
```

##### 2. the content of Dockerfile

**consumer:**

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

COPY consumer.py /
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install kafka-python
```

**producer**

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

COPY producer.py /
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install kafka-python
```

##### 3. the content of consumer.py related changes

make the same changes in the *producer.py* file.

```py
import json
import os
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer

kafka_server = ["kafka:9092"]
......
```

##### 4. try to rebuild and restart your project

`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build`

**then, after waiting 1 or 2 minutes,i found the output is fine.**

- *Maybe this related to the default session timeout of kafka consumer.*

---

i know above isnot the best answer but can solve the problem.

Comment: Hi lemoana, thanks for your suggestion, but my question is about how to setup network to make kafka container, producer container and consumer container communicate together

Comment: **1.** i use `docker-compose up -d` to start project, and could access to container-*kafka* inside other container. **2.** And if your use `docker network ls`, you can find the network-*deploy_kafka_docker_default* which created by the project itself by default. So what exactly do you mean **setup network to make ... communicate together ?**, and could you post the detail output of this?

Comment: sorry lemona, I modified and added more detail about my question, the producer seems cannot find kafka broker, I think might be network setting problem

Comment: thanks lemona,  I followed your new instruction, but still get no broker available error. I set the kafka_server to the local server IP already. not sure why

Comment: @宏宇魏 did you make it work?